# How can I solve this Visual studio error showing in my console?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to write my first code in Visual Studio, but this error appears on the console. How can I get rid of it?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int sum1 = 100 + 50;       // 150 (100 + 50)
    int sum2 = sum1 + 250;     // 400 (150 + 250)
    int sum3 = sum2 + sum2;    // 800 (400 + 400)
    cout << sum1 << "\n";
    cout << sum2 << "\n";
    cout << sum3;
    return 0;
}
```

> '"c:\users\333a\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> Press any key to contiinue . . .

[image]

Comment: It might have to do with having a space in the file path? Or having the file path be too long?

Comment: Your picture says the file was not saved. Although Visual Studio by default saves when you compile.

Comment: Oh, and the file does not look like it is part of the project or solution, it seems to just be a file.

Comment: You can make it part of the project by right clicking "Source Files" at the right hand side an "Add Existing File" or something similar.

Comment: make certain that the file does indeed exist where the console believes it should exist and if it does, ensure that it is an executable file.

Comment: I think that is the problem `Source1.cpp` is not part of the project so it was not built.

Comment: Side note: You almost never want to use an image as a primary source of information in a question, but in this case it's pretty much the only source if information you've got. The lack of anything in the build output is very odd. This backs up @drescherjm 's suspicion. I don't think we can give you a concrete answer explaining exactly went wrong, but if it does come down to no files compiled because no files are in the project, you should delete the question because any answers it does get, add the files to the project, aren't going to be much help to future askers.

Answer (score 1):

Source1.cpp is currently not part of the project you are trying to run. It is just a file, as far as Visual Studio is aware, it is NOT related the program you are trying to run.

Visual Studio does not currently think any files are related to the program you are trying to run, so when you try to run the program, nothing happens, because there is nothing to run.

You need to add this file to your Visual Studio project. This can be done by right clicking "Source Files" at the right hand side, and selecting Add -> Existing Item. Future files can also be created with Add -> New Item.